# squared with a negative number

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation, radicals

So I am trying to understand this formula.

[image: Visual represenatation]

I get that 7 squared is 7 * 7 = 49;
However the () scares me, I get that there are rules for what to do first but they always confuse me.
How does (-2) squared become 4 I know that two of `-` becomes a + somehow, could someone write out the simple formula for (-2) becoming 4

Comment: What is $(-2)\cdot (-2)$?

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses mean do this first, so you negate the $2$ before squaring.  We have $$(-2)^2=(-2)\cdot (-2)=4$$

Comment: Why not do -2 * -2? Wouldnt that be the same?

Comment: Yes.  I thought having the parentheses emphasized that we are multiplying $-2$ by $-2$.  Without the parentheses in the original problem most people would read $-2^2$ as $-(2^2)=-4$ or at least be worried that was what was intended.

Comment: Ohhh, so it's only so we can read it easier?

Comment: Pretty much, @Varga   Although we need the left-hand side of $(-2)^2 = -2\cdot -2 = 4$ to help avoid ambiguities, at a minimum, because, given the usual precedence of operators, as Ross notes,  when we write only  $-2^2$, it is to be evaluated as $-(2^2)= -(4) = -4$.  So $(-2)^2 \neq -2^2$, but on the right hand side, we can certainly write $(-2)^2 = -2 \cdot -2$.